# Merge SVG shapes or paths

Tags: html, svg, merge, path, union

I am trying to create custom map geographies using 30k underlying SVG paths/shapes.

[image: 1]

I want to merge shapes of same colour and then create and outline border for the merged SVG shapes/paths.

It would be great if you could guide me on how to do this. Wasn’t able to find any solution yet.

One way was to hide the outlines but if the colour of two neighbouring boundaries is same we would not be able to distinguish the two geographies.

Thanks in advance

[image: 2]

Comment: It all starts by you posting code you tried, so we can help you fix it. Now, you want us to do your job.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not able to distinguish states from counties? Search for class names or some other attribute on the path elements.

Comment: Wouldn't merging paths of the same color have the same problem as the second image you have shown?